# Capistrano custom strategy without making a gem

Tags: capistrano

Is there a way of making a custom deploy strategy for capistrano, but without having to bundle it as a gem? I've searched and searched but everyone's examples are packaged as gems.

I just want to stick it in the include path and require it in the Capfile.

Comment: Any updates on this? Did you use @lars-strojny suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
require 'capistrano/recipes/deploy/strategy/remote_cache'
class InsaneStrategy < Capistrano::Deploy::Strategy::RemoteCache
  def copy_repository_cache
     do_something()
  end
end

set :strategy, InsaneStrategy.new(self)
```